# Probability of correctly ordering two measurements

Tags: probability, distributions, ranking

I am measuring two points x and y with some normally distributed noise associated with each point, and want to determine which is greater:

x_measured = Normal(x_mean, x_sd)

y_measured = Normal(y_mean, y_sd)

Is there a way that can calculate the odds that I correctly order x_measured and y_measured ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ah - I've figured it out. Let:

d = x_mean - y_mean

sd_avg = sqrt(x_sd^2 + y_sd^2)

d_star = d / sd_avg

Then the likelihood of correctly ordering is the CDF (area under the normal(1,1) curve) of d_star.